# How to iterate over a column vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, iteration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I iterate through each element in an n-dimensional matrix in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758736/how-do-i-iterate-through-each-element-in-an-n-dimensional-matrix-in-matlab)

I have a column vector `list` which I would like to iterate like this:

```
for elm in list
   //do something with elm
```

How?

Comment: I'll also have you know, googling the terms "iterate over matrix matlab" returns stackoverflow as the number 2 result.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

In Matlab, you can iterate over the elements in the list directly. This can be useful if you don't need to know which element you're currently working on.

Thus you can write

```
for elm = list
%# do something with the element
end
```

Note that Matlab iterates through the columns of `list`, so if `list` is a nx1 vector, you may want to transpose it.

Comment: Also not good if you want to change the value of the containing elements

Comment: If you don't know whether list is a column or a row vector, you can use the rather ugly combination `(:)'`: `for elm = list(:)'; %... ;end`. The combination `(:)'` will create row vectors from matrices too, so handle with care.

Comment: you mean `(:).'` right? Otherwise you are using the complex conjugate operator instead of the transpose operator.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: If you know that your data do not contain complex numbers, `(:)'` will work just fine - though it may be good practice to use `(:).'` regardless.

Answer (score 31):

```
for i=1:length(list)
  elm = list(i);
  //do something with elm.
```

Answer (score 6):

with many functions in matlab, you don't need to iterate at all.

for example, to multiply by it's position in the list:

```
m = [1:numel(list)]';
elm = list.*m;
```

vectorized algorithms in matlab are in general much faster.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to apply a function to each element and put the results in an output array, you can use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html).

As others have pointed out, for most operations, it's best to avoid loops in MATLAB and [vectorise your code instead](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1109.html).