# How to find nearest two points between two matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, coordinates, point, closest

I have

```
X = (Yt.*sin(W))-(Xt.*cos(W));
Y = (Yt.*cos(W))+(Xt.*sin(W));  % which give the coordinates X and Y. 
X_inv = R.*sin(B_involute); 
Y_inv = R.*cos(B_involute);     % which give the coordinates X_inv and Y_inv.
```

I need to find the nearest two points between `X`, `Y` and `X_inv`, `Y_inv`.

lots of thanks from now.

Comment: When coming with question about exercise/homework you should show **your own** attempts before posting it on SO. SO is not a code factory.

Comment: I could show my whole program but I just need somebody to suggest me a way/ idea. not a code !! just chill out.  by the way, This is not a homework. just trying to learn Matlab well.

Comment: Show what you have already tried, what part of the problem you don't understand. And then we're always glad to help :)

Comment: Let me be more clear. I have tried to understand "dsearchn" command. and knnsearch. However, I could not understand. I am stucked with this step. I want to go further but trying to understand in which way. All I am applied was wrong and meaningless. Thus, How could I show this to you? I want to learn how I can find that point? in which way? any recommandation or documents link? I hope I could explain myself. thanks for your trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the pair-wise distances efficiently using [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html)

```
D = pdist2( [X(:) Y(:)], [X_inv(:) Y_inv(:)] );
```

Once you have the pairwise distances, it is easy to find the minimal distance

```
[md mi] = min(D(:));
```

Conver linear index into pair index

```
[idx, inv_idx] = ind2sub( size(D), mi );
```

The result

```
fprintf(1, 'Closest points are [%d]: (%f,%f) -> [%d]: (%f,%f)\n',...
        idx, X(idx), Y(idx), inv_idx, X_inv(inv_idx), Y_inv(inv_idx) );
```

Comment: I appreciate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984199/how-to-find-nearest-two-points-between-two-matrices/33984933#33984933

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you some clues:

1. Use [loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758736/how-do-i-iterate-through-each-element-in-an-n-dimensional-matrix-in-matlab) to iterate over each X and Y elements in both matrices.
2. Use [Euclidean Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) to get distance between current points.
3. Take minimal of all distances that you got.